How thick would a coin have to be s.t. the probability to land on its "side" is exactly 1/3?
Assume a coin of uniform density with fixed radius $r$ is thrown from a height $x$ with $x>r$, $|\vec\omega|=1$, direction uniformly distributed. Assume the coin "lands" on the side closest to the ground upon its surface first contacting the ground. What would its thickness $l$ have to be so that the coin behaves as a three-sided die?
About the need to specify the physical situation:
On second thought. My guess is that given some bounce behaviour, i.e. hard cut-off, exponential decay of energy per bounce or similar, the fixed-point of the problem, i.e. when the thickness is such that all probabilities are equal, the thickness is independent of the precise details of the bounces.

"Assume the coin "lands" on the side closest to the ground upon first contacting the ground." This doesn't entirely make sense. Can we assume the "ground" is an intangible surface? Because otherwise it seem that a "side" can't "first contact" the ground. A edge/corner would hit first and cause the coin to go bouncing around (like when you flip a real coin).

My gut feeling is $\ell = r/2$. If viewed as a 2d problem you might want to make the areas all equal. But if though of as a 1d problem where we look "down" the rotation axis, it seems like the total lengths should be equal. Luckily in either case the answer is $\ell=r/2$.

(But I'm worried about taking into account the ground surface and the fact that there is another special direction--the direction of gravity. So I am not confident enough to post an answer. I hope someone else can.)

An old question on this topic, without a satisfactory answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33831/123208

ArXiv paper link taken from the above-\linked other answer: https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4559

One of the problems is that a real coin would not function like one from a model. Even assuming perfectly smooth sides and a perfectly smooth floor, it would still behave oddly when it hits a literal boundary condition like landing on a pointed edge.

I wonder if there's a way to answer this kind of question with stat mech. Assume a hard cylinder bouncing elastically on an infinite plane. With enough energy in the system it will (presumably) bounce around chaotically, sampling almost all of its phase space. But reduce the energy enough and phase space becomes divided into three, corresponding to heads, tails and edge. The question is, just at the critical point, what fraction of phase space ends up in each? And for what aspect ratio of cylinder is it $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$? I don't fancy trying to do such a calculation but maybe it can be done.

Thinking a bit more, I think the method I described above will give the same result as Willy Wallace's answer, just with a different physical explanation. The critical energy level occurs when the coin has just enough energy to balance on the sharp edge between a face and its "edge", so that it can just tip over from one basin to another. We want it to spend equal time in each basin, and I think there's an entropic argument that this happens when the edge subtends the same solid angle as each of the two faces. If I can see a way to make that argument properly I'll post an answer.

Matt Parker (Stand-Up Maths) looked into this without conclusion. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qqPKKOU-yY

I'll try to generalize by reducing the case of different bouncing behaviors to the one proposed in the question.
With the prescribed rule, the coin bounces once, and only once. Suppose the bouncing behavior is different. We assume bouncing and the surface is infinitely 'sticky', such that upon landing the direction (i.e. two sphere) is mapped in a way that does not change the probability density of $p(\omega)$ after the bounce w.r.t. prior the bounce.
This can be realized if the bounce does not induce some bias towards a direction, e.g. by reversing one component (or all) of $\omega$. The components must be scaled equally though (which may not be the case since the friction induced from the relative motion of coin to ground is not necessarily the same as the friction from landing).
I will define the 'last relevant contact' as the earliest contact, such that by some decision rule (such as in the question, or by looking at whether the torque can overcome the angular velocity in time, before the coin lands) all subsequent bounces has the same result as the one of last relevant contact.
Because previous bounces do not affect the probability density (if they did, we would only need to look at the mapping of $\omega$ prior and after the bounce and analyse the resulting density. I.e. it won't be a simple rotation of the two-sphere), the last relevant contact might as well have been the first contact.
Then, due to the symmetry of the problem, assuming the coin starts 'parallel' to the surface, i.e. the cylinder circle is parallel to the ground, landing on any of the two edges has the same probability.
Given the decision rule of the question, Willy Wallace's answer provides the correct solution.
If the probability density has changed, due to bounces, we simply demand $\int_{\Omega_\text{cap}}p(\phi(\omega)) = \int_{\Omega_\text{band}}p(\phi(\omega))$.
What is unclear to me is why, just because $p(\omega)=\frac{1}{4\pi}$, this implies that $p(\phi)=\frac{1}{4\pi}$, which is why I have left it general here.
